# Using python to publish feature services to arcgis online WITHOUT Arcgis Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, feature-service, publishing, arcrest

My small non-profit currently uploads feature services manually by zipping shapefiles and "overwriting" them. I'm trying to automate this process in Python and have only come across `ago tools` and  `ArcREST`.  `ArcREST` seems to be the more robust module but its usability seems predicated on access to an ArcGIS Server  and we don't have that capacity at the moment. I see that there might be a way to create  `.sd` files and upload them using a Python script but I am confused on how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction with a sample script and/or some instructions on how to do this? I have ArcMap 10.2

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an ArcGIS Server license in order to work with ArcGIS Online hosted services. You can also create an `.sd` file having ArcGIS Desktop license only.

If your hosted feature service schema is not changing, you probably just want to truncate the feature layer and populate it with the features from your shapefile.

```
securityinfo = {}
securityinfo['security_type'] = 'Portal'
securityinfo['username'] = agol_admin_username
securityinfo['password'] = agol_admin_password
securityinfo['org_url'] = agol_org_url
securityinfo['proxy_url'] = None
securityinfo['proxy_port'] = None
securityinfo['referer_url'] = None
securityinfo['token_url'] = None
securityinfo['certificatefile'] = None
securityinfo['keyfile'] = None
securityinfo['client_id'] = None
securityinfo['secret_id'] = None

from arcresthelper import featureservicetools

fc = r"C:\GIS\Temp\Wells.shp"

#webmapid = 'long string'
fst = featureservicetools.featureservicetools(securityinfo)
fs = fst.GetFeatureService(itemId=webmapid,returnURLOnly=False)
fl = fst.GetLayerFromFeatureService(fs=fs,layerName='Wells',returnURLOnly=False)
print fl.query(returnCountOnly=True)

#delete all features (truncate)
fst.DeleteFeaturesFromFeatureLayer(fl.url, '1=1')

fl.addFeatures(fc=fc,attachmentTable=None)
print fl.query(returnCountOnly=True)

fl.deleteFeatures(objectIds='310078')
print fl.query(returnCountOnly=True)
```

If your shapefile might be different from the published hosted feature service in terms of fields definition, you might either edit the hosted feature service to reflect the changes (with [this sample](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/blob/master/samples/HostedFeatureServiceAdmin/addFieldToHostedFeatureService.py)) or by publishing `.sd` file which you can create in ArcMap from a shapefile (using `arcpy` and [this sample](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/example-publish-a-map-service-from-a-map-document-mxd-.htm) and then using [this ArcREST sample](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/blob/master/samples/publish_sd_to_service.py)).

Using [`arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/CreateMapSDDraft/00s30000006q000000/), it is possible to create a .sddraft without having a connection to ArcGIS Server. Specify the `server_type` parameter to be `MY_HOSTED_SERVICES`. Then use [`arcpy.StageService_server`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Stage_Service/00540000001r000000/) which will convert the draft to the `.sd` file.

You can then use [`arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Upload_Service_Definition/00540000001p000000/) to publish this `.sd` file on your ArcGIS Online organization.

Comment: this is a great resource and I'm leaning towards assuming that schema changes will be part of the updating of feature layers. I'd follow the 2nd sample however the latter sample links you posted specifically state "A connection to ArcGIS Server must be established in the catalog window of ArcMap before running this script" which is what I'm trying to avoid if I have no ArcGis Server set up.

Comment: @SteeleJohnson, I've updated my answer with additional details, hope this will make it clearer for you.

Comment: Hi @Alex  is there a way to convert from shapefile to SDDraft instead of from MapDocument to SDDraft? I haven't seen anything quite that does this.

Comment: @SteeleJohnson, unfortunately, the feature service is based on the map document which means if you want to automate the whole workflow, you would need to add a shapefile to a map document with `arcpy` and save it then before converting further to `.sd`. Look here for a sample: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/adding-shapefile-or-feature-class-as-layer-in-arcgis-desktop-using-python-arcpy

Comment: I see. The only issue is I wouldn't want to have an mxd for each shapefile I want to publish separately. It'd be easier to figure out a way to publish shapefiles from a .gdb or even just stored in a specific folder.

Comment: @SteeleJohnson, I usually solve this by having an empty map document (a template with no layers) and then adding shapefiles on demand, saving to another .mxd before publishing, and then deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll look into getting Server.