# Adding Shapefile to Multiple Data Frames using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, layers, data-frame

I'm trying to simply add a shapefile to 2 data frames of a Map Document, the shapefile is already in a third dataframe of the same Map Document. I was using the guide below but am getting the following error: ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source

[Adding shapefile or feature class as layer in ArcGIS Desktop using Python/ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/adding-shapefile-or-feature-class-as-layer-in-arcgis-desktop-using-python-arcpy)

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import arcpy.mapping 
env.workspace = "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/501_Customization                               /lab4/E_ercise_10_export/Austin"

#Get Shapefile
parkslayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/Users/Chris/Documents/501_Customization/lab4/E_ercise_10_export/Austin/parks.shp")

#Get Map Document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#Get data frames
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0, 1]

# add the layer to the map at the bottom of the TOC in data frame 0 and 1
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, parkslayer, "BOTTOM")

# Refresh things
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df1, parks

print "Shapefile successfully added to data frames"
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include the error message text in full

Answer (score 1):

The Mapping Layer class `arcpy.mapping.Layer()` must refer to either a Layer File or a Layer in the ArcMap TOC.  It can't reference a shapefile

```
parkslayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/Users/Chris/Documents/501_Customization/lab4/E_ercise_10_export/Austin/parks.shp")
```

You have a few options here:

1. Point `arcpy.mapping.Layer()` to your existing layer (in dataframe 3) and add that layer into your other two dataframes.  This would be the way I'd do it, as this would also pull through any symbology and definition queries if present.
2. Use [`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) to allow arcpy to see it as a layer
3. [Create a layer file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/saving-layers-and-layer-packages.htm) that references your shapefile, and point your `arcpy.mapping.Layer()` to that

Try this update to your code for option #1 above:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/501_Customization                               /lab4/E_ercise_10_export/Austin"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df3 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Name of DF 3")[0]
parkslayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "name of layer in DF 3", df3)[0]

# Get other dataframes
dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0, 1]

for df in dfs:
    # add the layer to the map at the bottom of the TOC in data frame 0 and 1
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, parkslayer, "BOTTOM")

# Refresh things
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()

print "Shapefile successfully added to data frames"
```